# how to combine columns into a single cell with different indexes?

Tags: r

I need to combine multiple values into a single cell. I do not know how to do this. What my data looks like:

| f1 | f2 | f1.1 | f2.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1: 30 | 2: 40 | 1: 30 | 3:70 |
| 1: 30 | 2: 40 | 1: 30 | 3:70 |

When I do a merge I get it:
How do I get away from this option?

| f1 | f1.1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1: 30 2: 40 | 1: 30 3:70 |
| 1: 30 2: 40 | 1: 30 3:70 |

What I want to get:

| f1 |
| --- |
| 1: 30 2:40 3:70 |
| 1: 30 2:40 3:70 |

Update: I completely forgot, in my dataframe, the data is in this format,

| f1 | g1 | h1 | f1.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1: 30 | 1:80 | 1: 60 | 2:70 |
| 1: 30 | 1:80 | 1: 60 | 2:70 |

How to do it:

| f1 |
| --- |
| 1: 30 2:70 |
| 1: 30 2:70 |

Comment: Post your data using `dput()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the updated question:
You could use `unite` from `tidyr` package

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%  unite("f1", c(f1, f1.2), sep = " ") %>% 
  select(-g1, -h1)
```

Output:

```
  f1        
  <chr>     
1 1: 30 2:70
2 1: 30 2:70
```

Data:

```
df <- tribble(
~f1, ~g1, ~h1, ~f1.2,
"1: 30", "1: 80", "1: 60", "2:70",
"1: 30", "1: 80", "1: 60", "2:70")
```

Comment: is it possible not to enter columns manually, but to get them dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

paste the unique values for each row together.

```
result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(unique(x), collapse = ' '))

data.frame(result)

#            result
#1 1: 30 2: 40 3:70
#2 1: 30 2: 40 3:70
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = paste0(unique(c_across()), collapse = ' '))
```

Comment: I don't understand where to enter what, could you write where to enter df?

Comment: and if my columns don't go in a row?

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 1):

```
data.frame(result = do.call(paste, unique(as.list(df))))
            result
1 1: 30 2: 40 3:70
2 1: 30 2: 40 3:70
```

Comment: instead of df you need to insert your dataframe? for some reason it doesn't change for me

Answer (score 1):

For your updated question, you can try

```
data.frame(f1 = do.call(paste,c(df[c("f1","f1.2")])))
```